# LoginWithApp always results in "Unable to communicate" response

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the C# Facebook SDK for Windows & Windows Phone on Windows Phone 8 and trying to use the `LoginWithApp` approach:

```
public void Authenticate()
{
    SessionStorage.Remove();

    var client = new FacebookSessionClient(this.appId);
    client.LoginWithApp("basic_info,read_stream,read_friendlist", "custom_state_string");
}
```

If I use the above code, it works fine in the emulator using the Login Simulator, but on a physical device I **always** get the following error response:

"(No connection to facebook - #2002) Connection failed: Unable to communicate with facebook in order to get the access token"

However, this can't be a simple communication problem because if I remove the `read_friendlist` permission it works every time.

Can anyone explain what's going on and how to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**read_friendlist** should be **read_friendlists** with an S on the end.